# How to prevent WhatsApp images and other local pictures folders appearing from Google+ Photos app?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I've enabled auto backup for camera photos except local folders. Although local folders are not uploaded to the cloud, Photos app keeps showing these folders and making a mess. I'd like to have this app clean with only camera photos just like Dropbox's Carousel do.

Comment: You may be able to create a blank file named ".nomedia" (yes the period is needed; the quotes aren't) in the folders you don't want it to index using a file manager. Then reboot the phone. This *should* prevent them from showing, but not always. Also it could cause problems for the apps that rely on those photos, so this may not be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 2021**: How to do it in the new [image] [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en) Android app:

1. Open **Google Photos**.
2. Click on your avatar in the upper right corner.
3. Click on **Photo Settings**.
4. Click on **Backup & Sync**.
5. Click on **Back up device folders**
6. A list of folders will appear with a toggle on the right.
7. Toggle on / off the folders you want to back up.

**Update 2014**: How to do it in the new [image] [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en) Android app:

1. Open **Google Photos**.
2. Go to **Settings** on the left panel.
3. Click on **Backup & Sync**.
4. Scroll down a bit.
5. Click on **Choose folders to back up...**
6. Activate or deactivate each folder by clicking the switch.

**Google+**

From: [Back up photos & videos automatically](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en)

Turn on or off for individual folders

1. Open the Photos app [image].
2. Touch the menu icon [image]  at the top left and then **On Device.**
3. To the right of each folder title, touch the cloud icon to turn Auto Backup on or off for that folder:

[image] Auto Backup is on for that folder.

[image] Auto Backup is off for that folder.

Comment: new version of photos app doen't have this option. .nomedia works perfect.

Comment: @shailesh thanks for noticing, updated with new steps.

Answer (score -1):

Goto accounts > Google > sync > un tick   pictures

Comment: It sounds like OP wants camera pictures to still be synced, this will break that.